# App Engine YAML file not running scripts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

All other static files are serving as normal at domain.

It seems PHP file wasn't running; when I don't try to run it as a script (and just upload it as a static file) it works fine; returning plaintext when jQuery calls it - so its definitely not a file path problem.

But once I list it as a php file in yaml and expect the jQuery to GET 'hello, world!' it returns 404 in the Firefox network monitor and there's a no response in the console.

Is there something I'm missing with regard to running a solitary server-side php script on App Engine Standard?

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# Serve php scripts another way.
- url: /scripts/elastic.php
  script: scripts/elastic.php

# Handle the main page by serving the index page.
# Note the $ to specify the end of the path, since app.yaml does prefix matching.
- url: /$
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html


# Handle folder urls by serving the index.html page inside.
- url: /(.*)/$
  static_files: \1/index.html
  upload: .*/index.html

# Handle nearly every other file by just serving it.
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
```

**elastic.php**

```
<?php
return 'Hello, world!'
?>
```

**script.js (called after jQuery loads in my index.html)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("./scripts/elastic.php", function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that your final `handlers` directive is telling the deployment to treat all files in your application as uploadable and static. I believe this is resulting in your calls to the earlier script being mishandled (maybe an App Engine bug...).

If you change your final handler to be either a PHP script or something like the following then you should be mostly good:

```
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)\.html
```

You'll also want to have your PHP script [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) results in the response rather than `return`, which doesn't actually return anything to the browser for display.

Comment: You're 100% correct! For some reason I thought it cascaded such that the initial script handler had caught all php files before they could get further down the funnel. I adjusted the title so your answer can help more people. Thanks Brett :)

Comment: It is supposed to operate that way for at least the URL matching, but I think during the upload process the file is getting overwritten or reclassified as static. I will open a bug about the behavior and see what comes of that. Might just be that we need to warn people in the docs that this can happen.