# Goole App Engine - Deployed PHP app does not recognize php files

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have deployed my web app - a php app in google app engine. App.yaml code

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
#threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /mail
  static_dir: www/mail
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /mail/.*
  script: www/mail/mailsender_1.php
- url: /(.*)$
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

However, when `/mail/mailsender_1.php` is called from javascript - ajax call, it does not recognize `mailsender_1.php` as php script. I have spent a complete day on debugging. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By looking at your issue and comparing with this [community question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917832/app-engine-yaml-file-not-running-scripts), it occured to me that the issue might be the final handler, not the `/mail/.*` one. The accepted answer suggest that the final handler is making the deploy think that all files in your `www/` directory are static and uploadable, including `.php` scripts. My suggestion would be to change the `upload: www/(.*)` directive to `upload: www/(.*)\.jpg` or any other file extention you have to give it a try. Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer and I could able to change my app.yaml file runtime: php55
api_version: 1
#threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /mail/.*
  script: www/mail/mailsender_1.php
- url: /(.*)$
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|map|woff)

Comment: So it did work? I will add all that to a proper answer so that the community can see that the issue is fixed, and so that you can accept/upvote it, if it is the case.

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer provided below so the community can see that you've been sufficiently helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your issue and comparing with this [community question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917832/app-engine-yaml-file-not-running-scripts), it occured to me that the issue you are facing is due the `/(.*)$` handler, not the `/mail/.*` one.

The accepted answer on that post suggest that your `/(.*)$` handler is making the deploy think that all files in your `www/` directory are static and uploadable, including `.php` scripts.

My suggestion would be to change the `upload: www/(.*)` directive to `upload: www/(.*)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|map|woff)` as it will suit all file extention you have, according to the comments.

So your handler section should look like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /mail
  static_dir: www/mail
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /mail/.*
  script: www/mail/mailsender_1.php
- url: /(.*)$
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|map|woff)
```